# Create an image that will transform into another upon being clicked...Windows 8 VS Blend

Tags: c#, windows-8, expression-blend

I am creating an app where I want my image of a burger for example to change into fries when clicked. I am creating this in blend because I know I want to make storyboards and then go from there but I am totally lost on how to go about this.

Any tips on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a storyboard that change opacity of two images with blend. Then you can call the storyboard.begin() to run the storyboard you want for example from the tapped or click event.